# Arranging canvas layers

Tags: javascript, canvas

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div style="position: absolute; left: 10px; top: 10px; width:200px; height:100px; background-color: yellow;">
        <FORM><INPUT TYPE="button" onClick="history.go(0)" VALUE="Restart!"></FORM>
    </div>

    <div style="position: absolute; z-index: 1; left: 50px; top: 20px; width:100px; height:20px;">
        <canvas width="400" height="500" class="codehs-editor-canvas"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>
```

Why isn't the button on top of the canvas please help, I have tried rearranging the code, but always the canvas is on top. Please help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/InferOn/264Ty/

Quoted from [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)

> The z-index CSS property specifies the z-order of an element and its
>   descendants. When elements overlap, z-order determines which one
>   covers the other. An element with a larger z-index generally covers an
>   element with a lower one.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div style="position: absolute;z-index: 2; left: 10px; top: 10px; width:200px; height:100px; background-color: yellow;">
        <FORM><INPUT TYPE="button" onClick="history.go(0)" VALUE="Restart!"></FORM>
    </div>

    <div style="position: absolute; z-index: 1; left: 50px; top: 20px; width:100px; height:20px;">
        <canvas width="400" height="500" class="codehs-editor-canvas"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>
```